# Does someone knows if Facebook liberated their photo uploader (open source)?

Tags: facebook, photo, uploader

I've heard that Facebook used an (open source?) solution for the photo uploader... and that they liberated the code some time ago... Anyone knows something about that or where to find it? Thanks!

Comment: If you could provide references to where you heard this from, I am sure someone here can tell you more. For now, refer to the Facebook Open Source page which should contain a comprehensive list of libraries and frameworks used and extended by Facebook http://developers.facebook.com/opensource/. However, I could not find anything about a photo uploader there, so I assume it has not been open sourced.

Comment: Thanks! i'll search for more info!

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be that Facebook hasn't released their Photo album system to the public. Thanks @Kariem for your help!